# Is it possible to view each of cucumber scenario step result with TestNG in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, testng-eclipse

[image]

Please refer to attached screen shot, with Junit one can see each of the scenario steps results but with TestNG it's not showing the same.

Is it possible with TestNG as well ? Am I missing any configuration, with JUnit it just works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research I've found that there are several tickets for this and similar questions on SO. Maybe the following will provide more info.

At the moment, for `cucumber-jvm` release version `1.2.5`, features are run as a single TestNG test (as you can see in the image below)

[image]

This [ticket](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1113) was open and not long ago and they have added the functionality to run a TestNG test for each scenario (pull request [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/1174)).

Because these changes are not released yet, in order to get TestNG to run for each scenario, you have to do a few things:

- project used to test this `->` [here](https://github.com/mikejramsey56/java-calculator-testng). (I used IntelliJ for this project, same thing can be done in Eclipse)
- update `pom.xml` so you can use the `master` branch of `cucumber-jmv`, and therefore have the latest changes. Below are the changes I've made.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<parent>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>java-calculator-testng</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Examples: Java Calculator TestNG</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

- go to `src/test/java`, open `RunCukesTest` and run it. Here are the results:

[image]

I'm sure you can apply the `testng.xml` to make it run as you wish.

Unfortunatelly for now, **`steps`** are still not shown. Will probably be added in future releases, it's the next logical step.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I've referred to embedded github project itself to setup TestNG + Cucumber. But even after mentioning class name per your suggestion, result doesn't show each of the steps. Please let me know if it's working at your end ?

Comment: Thanks for this info, isn't this should issue for TestNG github repo instead of cucumber-jvm ? I looked into the ticket but it doesn't talk about this particular issue

Comment: I went ahead and filed the issue https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/350

Comment: `cucumber-testng` library is responsible for how the tests are shown, but the ticket you've opened might help to get steps to show. I've updated my answer @vikramvi

Comment: I didn't understand how RunCukesTest class picked up basic_arithmetic.feature , can you please clarify ? Per my understanding feature file name needs to be explicitly mentioned along within @CucumberOptions

Comment: RunCukesTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests which has a DataProvider method that calls `provideScenarios()`. it probably looks for a default location in the same package. Check RuntimOptions class, provided by cucumber.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications, I've accepted your answer.